# Can't redirect Devise sign page to show profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I'm hoping someone can help. I am using the Devise gem for registering and signing in users. I have a Profile controller. When an existing user logs in, I want them to be diverted to the Profile's show.html.erb page in order to view their profile. I would expect this would be done under the Sessions controller but it doesn't seem to do anything

The Sessions controller code is:

```
class Registrations::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  protected
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      profile_path(resource)
    end
```

However, when a user registers, the redirect works successfully under the Registrations controller below:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      new_profile_path(resource)
    end.
```

I also want to have a link to the users Profile page when they are logged in but when I do it throws up the following error

application.html.erb code for the link is below (I have tried a number of different variables in place of the '@profile' but with no success)

```
 <li><%= link_to 'Show Profile', profile_path(@profile), :class => 'navbar-link' %></li>
```

The error I receive is:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Profiles#index

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My routes (which I'm not sure are setup correctly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :profiles
  get 'profiles/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
  get '/profiles/new' => 'profiles#new'
  get '/profiles/edit' => 'profiles#edit'
  get '/profiles/index' => 'profiles#index'

  root to: 'pages#index'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Lastly, my Profile controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @search = Profile.search(params[:q])
    @profiles = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new  
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.save
      format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Your Profile was successfully created' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entry }
    end
  end   
end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|

    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end

  def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params[:profile][:user_id] = current_user.id
      params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :contact_number, :location, :makeup_type, :bio, :user_id, :image)
    end    
end
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application controller you want something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    profile_path(current_user)
  end
  #user is the model name for example that you created with devise

end
```

Comment: This redirected straight away to the profile so I've marked it as correct regarding routing it. Should I have declared my after_sign_up_path_for(resource) in the application controller also instead of the Registrations? Which would be a better way of doing thing and why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there are two problems:

1. Redirecting after sign in
2. Url generation error in the application layout

**Redirecting after sign in**

You need to add the controller to your routes definition (like you have registrations.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations", sessions: 'registrations/sessions' }
```

**Url generation error in the application layout**

I assume that the profile model is associated with the user (e.g. profile belongs_to user, or maybe user has_one profile). I also assume that you want to have a link for the current user's profile.

If that is the case then you could most likely do something like this:

```
<%= if current_user %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to 'Show Profile', profile_path(current_user.profile), :class => 'navbar-link' %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise, you should set `@profile` in some `before_action` in the application controller or in any controller that uses the application layout.

Comment: Thanks very much. The link above worked. So thank you. As for the redirecting after sign in, I seemed to have issues when I added the routing above. I think it was more to do with how I had declared things through out my application. I'm not sure. In the end I placed the after_sign_in_path_for in the application controller as per Gurmukh's answer below. I have up marked you by a few. Thanks again.